# Asp.Net MVC4 searching ViewBag array of Objects

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4

Got this code in my view:

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(ViewBag.EventTypes, (x) => (x.EventCode == Row.EventCode));
```

Getting this exception:

```
error CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
```

How can I do this in my view? I need to search the object array in the viewbag for the EventCode. Or is there another way to do this?

The array is defined and set like this:

```
// mycorses is a list of events.
EventTypes[] etypes = GetEventTypes(mycourses);
ViewBag.EventTypes = etypes;
```

This is the EventTypes object definition:

```
public class EventTypes
{
    public string EventCode { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to cast the lambda as the error says. Change `(x) => (x.EventCode == Row.EventCode)` to this: `(Func<EventTypes, bool>)(x => x.EventCode == "A")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply can add `as EventTypes[]` and it should work:

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(ViewBag.EventTypes as EventTypes[],
                           (x) => (x.EventCode == Row.EventCode));
```